# How can I (in D3) make a rectangle change its size while staying fix in one point?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent

With one click on the canvas I am trying to create a rectangle. While holding the click, its size should be changing based on the coordinates of the pointer. The width and height changes while the upper left corner is staying still.

The rectangle changes its form from left to right, but I also want it to go from right to left as soon as the current x Value becomes smaller than the x value of the fixed point. Can somebody help me with this problem? How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot!

```js
const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 60},
        chartWidth = width  - margin.left - margin.right,
        chartHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      let shouldAppear = false;

      const svg = d3.select('svg')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + left + "," + top + ")");

        svg.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'canvas')
        .attr('width', chartWidth)
        .attr('height', chartHeight)
        
      svg.on('mousedown', function(){
        shouldAppear = true;
        const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        rectangle.attr('y', mouse[1])
          .attr('x', mouse[0])
        
      })
      svg.on('mousemove', function(){
        const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        
        if (shouldAppear){ 
          rectangle
              .attr('width', Math.abs(mouse[0] - rectangle.attr('x')))
              .attr('height', Math.abs(mouse[1] - rectangle.attr('y')))
          }
      }) 
      svg.on('mouseup', function(){
        shouldAppear = false;
        rectangle
        .attr('width', 0)
        .attr('height', 0)
      });
      let rectangle = svg
          .append('rect')
          .attr('class', 'rectangle')
          .attr('width', 0)
          .attr('height', 0)
          .style('fill','red')  
    }
```

Comment: The issue is that width and height for rectangles cannot be negative numbers. I am composing a solution and will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when the pointer goes left or top of the starting point, your calculation for the width and height turns negative, and svg does not allow negative values for `width` or `height` for `rect` elements.

A solution is to save the mouse starting position in the `mousedown` function as `mousestart`:

```
let mousestart; 
svg.on("mousedown", function () {
  shouldAppear = true;
  const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  mousestart = mouse;
  rectangle.attr("y", mouse[1]).attr("x", mouse[0]);
});
```

Then use the `mousestart` position to evaluate if the cursor is to the left, right, top or bottom of the starting position, and create specific adjustments to the rectangle as needed in each case in your `mousemove` function.

```
svg.on("mousemove", function () {
  const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  if (shouldAppear) {
    let x = mouse[0] - mousestart[0]; //negative values indicate cursor moved left
    let y = mouse[1] - mousestart[1]; //negative values indicate cursor moved up
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0) { // if the cursor moved right and down from starting position
      rectangle
        .attr("width", Math.abs(mouse[0] - rectangle.attr("x")))
        .attr("height", Math.abs(mouse[1] - rectangle.attr("y")));
    } 
    if (x <= 0){ // if the cursor moved left
      rectangle
        .attr('x', mouse[0]) // move the rectangle to the new cursor x position
        .attr('width', mousestart[0] - mouse[0] ) // the width of the rectangle is now the difference between the starting point and current x point
        .attr("height", Math.abs(mouse[1] - rectangle.attr("y"))); // the height is calculated based on the difference between the current position and the rectangle y
    }
    if (y <= 0) { // if the cursor moved up similar calculations as above but in the y direction
      rectangle
        .attr('y', mouse[1])
        .attr('height', mousestart[1] - mouse[1] )
        .attr("width", Math.abs(mouse[0] - rectangle.attr("x")));
    }
    if (x <= 0 && y <= 0 ) { // if the cursor moved left and up similar calculations as above but in both x and y direction
      rectangle
        .attr('x', mouse[0])
        .attr('y', mouse[1])
        .attr('width', mousestart[0] - mouse[0] )
        .attr('height', mousestart[1] - mouse[1] )
    }
  }
});
```

Check the full working snippet:

```js
let width = 400,
  height = 400;

const margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 60 },
  chartWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
  chartHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
let shouldAppear = false;

const svg = d3
  .select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "canvas")
  .attr("width", chartWidth)
  .attr("height", chartHeight - 10);


let mousestart; 

svg.on("mousedown", function () {
  shouldAppear = true;
  const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  mousestart = mouse;
  rectangle.attr("y", mouse[1]).attr("x", mouse[0]);
});
svg.on("mousemove", function () {
  const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  if (shouldAppear) {
    let x = mouse[0] - mousestart[0]; //negative values indicate cursor moved left
    let y = mouse[1] - mousestart[1]; //negative values indicate cursor moved up
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0) { // if the cursor moved right and down from starting position
      rectangle
        .attr("width", Math.abs(mouse[0] - rectangle.attr("x")))
        .attr("height", Math.abs(mouse[1] - rectangle.attr("y")));
    } 
    if (x <= 0){ // if the cursor moved left
      rectangle
        .attr('x', mouse[0]) // move the rectangle to the new cursor x position
        .attr('width', mousestart[0] - mouse[0] ) // the width of the rectangle is now the difference between the starting point and current x point
        .attr("height", Math.abs(mouse[1] - rectangle.attr("y"))); // the height is calculated based on the difference between the current position and the rectangle y
    }
    if (y <= 0) { // if the cursor moved up similar calculations as above but in the y direction
      rectangle
        .attr('y', mouse[1])
        .attr('height', mousestart[1] - mouse[1] )
        .attr("width", Math.abs(mouse[0] - rectangle.attr("x")));
    }
    if (x <= 0 && y <= 0 ) { // if the cursor moved left and up similar calculations as above but in both x and y direction
      rectangle
        .attr('x', mouse[0])
        .attr('y', mouse[1])
        .attr('width', mousestart[0] - mouse[0] )
        .attr('height', mousestart[1] - mouse[1] )
    }
  }
});
svg.on("mouseup", function () {
  shouldAppear = false;
  rectangle.attr("width", 0).attr("height", 0);
});
let rectangle = svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "rectangle")
  .attr("width", 0)
  .attr("height", 0)
  .style("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

**Update**

An improvement in the `mousemove` function which is easier to read calculates the `rect` element's attributes `rectx`, `recty`, `rectwidth`, `rectheight` and use it to set the attributes. Note you will still need to capture the `mousestart` coordinates in the `mousedown` function as shown above.:

```
svg.on("mousemove", function () {
  const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  if (shouldAppear) {
    let rectx, recty, rectwidth, rectheight;
    if (mouse[0] < mousestart[0]) { // if cursor moved left
      rectx = mouse[0];
      rectwidth = mousestart[0] - mouse[0];
    } else {  // if cursor moved right
      rectx = mousestart[0];
      rectwidth = mouse[0] - mousestart[0];
    }

    if (mouse[1] < mousestart[1]) { // if cursor moved up
      recty = mouse[1];
      rectheight = mousestart[1] - mouse[1];
    } else {  // if cursor moved down
      recty = mousestart[1];
      rectheight = mouse[1] - mousestart[1];
    }

    rectangle
      .attr('x', rectx)
      .attr('y', recty)
      .attr('width', rectwidth)
      .attr('height', rectheight)
  }
});
```

See full snippet:

```js
let width = 400,
  height = 400;

const margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 60 },
  chartWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
  chartHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
let shouldAppear = false;

const svg = d3
  .select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "canvas")
  .attr("width", chartWidth)
  .attr("height", chartHeight - 10);

let mousestart;

svg.on("mousedown", function () {
  shouldAppear = true;
  const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  mousestart = mouse;
  rectangle.attr("y", mouse[1]).attr("x", mouse[0]);
});
svg.on("mousemove", function () {
  const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
  if (shouldAppear) {
    let rectx, recty, rectwidth, rectheight;
    if (mouse[0] < mousestart[0]) { // if cursor moved left
      rectx = mouse[0];
      rectwidth = mousestart[0] - mouse[0];
    } else {  // if cursor moved right
      rectx = mousestart[0];
      rectwidth = mouse[0] - mousestart[0];
    }

    if (mouse[1] < mousestart[1]) { // if cursor moved up
      recty = mouse[1];
      rectheight = mousestart[1] - mouse[1];
    } else {  // if cursor moved down
      recty = mousestart[1];
      rectheight = mouse[1] - mousestart[1];
    }
    
    rectangle
      .attr('x', rectx)
      .attr('y', recty)
      .attr('width', rectwidth)
      .attr('height', rectheight)
  }
});
svg.on("mouseup", function () {
  shouldAppear = false;
  rectangle.attr("width", 0).attr("height", 0);
});

let rectangle = svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "rectangle")
  .attr("width", 0)
  .attr("height", 0)
  .style("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you! I had a vague idea similar to that but I didn't know how to perform it. Is there any Literature that you can recommend me for d3? I am new to it and I want to learn more

Comment: Check the updated answer. There is plenty of examples online and stackoverflow is always helpful. It just takes some time to get through it. Also definitely go through the API and documentation.